# Configure django on sub directory

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

What I have:

Apache http server with 4 virtual servers with distinc domains:

```
www.mydomain.com points to /var/www/mydomain/htdocs (php code)
```

and it works. All other domains are irrelevant.

On another machine I've designed a django project with two apps, and it works well with the django's buit-in server.

What I need:

```
www.mydomain.com pointing to /var/www/mydomain/htdocs (php code)
www.mydomain.com/recsys pointing to /opt/repsys (django code)
```

I want to keep the PHP code on root and install the django inside /repsys.

I can put my django code on root but when I try to put inside /repsys I have two issues:

- I had to put /repsys on all urls of my settings.py file (this is not an issue but is weird to me)
- And I have this error from django code:

  Reverse for 'ajax' with arguments '(u'viewproject',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

I can see this is due to the change in url (now it includes /repsys) and django don't know how to reverse this url, but I have no idea how to fix that...

My django is: 1.5.1

Here is my wsgi.py

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/opt/repsys')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "repsys.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and my apache conf file for this virtual server:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
#WSGIPythonPath /opt/repsys/

<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess repsyssite display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup repsyssite

    ServerAdmin blahhh@gmail.com
    ServerName  www.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydomain/htdocs"

    WSGIScriptAlias /reprep /opt/repsys/repsys/wsgi.py
    Alias /reprep/static /opt/repsys/static_serve
    Alias /reprep/media /opt/repsys/media
    Alias /admin_media  /home/myuser/Django-1.5/django/contrib/admin/media

    <Directory opt/repsys>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

# Logfiles
    ErrorLog  /var/www/logs/glob/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/glob/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My main url.py includes:

```
url(r'^report/', include('report.urls', namespace="report")),
```

And my report/url.py includes:

```
url(r'^(?P<fn>\w+)/ajax/$', views.ajax, name='ajax'),
```

And here is the line that works when I put my project on root but fails when inside a sub folder:

```
$('#viewreportdiv').load("{% url 'report:ajax' 'viewproject' %}", {proj: id});
```

Can someone point how to fix that?

Comment: i believe the alias should define only one path at a time. so you try to define 2 different virtualhost with different ports for each one.

Comment: But it is working, with this configuration I can excute PHP on root and django on a subdir. The only problem is on django when I try to reverse an URL inside templates (or in views). It fails when inside a subdir, but runs nicely when django is the root. Everything else works fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this, but I finally got this working myself, so I thought I'd post it here.

I was able to solve this using the article that Graham Dumpleton did at http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

In the end, my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf` file looked as follows

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/var/www/html/mysite:/var/www/html/mysite/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /var/www/html/mysite/mysite_www/wsgi.py process-group=mysite

Alias /static/ /var/www/html/static/
Alias /docs/ /var/www/html/mysite/docs/_build/html/

<Directory /var/www/html/mysite/mysite_www>
<Files wsgi.py>
Allow from all
Order deny,allow
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Here I'm making use of the Apache subdir specified through `WSGIScriptAlias`, rather than using `<VirtualHost>`.

From there I can get to my php pages via: `http://myserver.com/` and to the django site vis `http://myserver.com/mysite/`.

Note, that I had to make sure to use the trailing slash when browsing to Django (1.7) otherwise I would get to the main page, but the url reversals in my template wouldn't be handled properly to get to child pages.