# What are the correct permissions and virtualhosts for running Django in a sub-directory?

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache

I'm trying to install and run Django in a sub-directory, to isolate it and a static html site in root; these two questions haven't helped and are very old: [install django on subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292195/install-django-on-subdirectory) and [Configure django on sub directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424852/configure-django-on-sub-directory)

Is this a file/folder permissions, Apache user, virtualhosts or Python issue?

Why are the .py files not executing?

---

**Outline:**

- I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Apache2 was already installed and is running
- Python3 and Django installed
- libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 installed and enabled
- `apachectl configtest` Syntax OK
- All files chowned to `www-data:www-data`

`/var/log/apache2/access.log` is empty

`/var/log/apache2/error.log` contains:

> [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 69090] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
> OpenSSL/1.1.1k mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal
> operations
>
> [core:notice] [pid 69090] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

---

I ran the usual shell commands to start a Django project:

`root@localhost:~# django-admin.py startproject contact`

and then I ran createsuperuser, collectstatic, etc., successfully.

I'm trying to use a Django form that is in /contact/contactform/templates/contact.html that contains this:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
            <div class="frc-captcha mb-2" data-sitekey={{ captcha_site_key }}></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

and going to https://example.com/contact/ throws a 403 error.

The .htaccess file at root has

```
RewriteEngine on
ServerSignature Off
Options All -Indexes
```

This is my public_html file structure:

[image]

**/contact/contact/settings.py**

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '...'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'contact.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'contact.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf:**

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

        #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
        #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>


Alias /static /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/static
Alias /media /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/media

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /contact/contact /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess contact python-home=/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact

WSGIProcessGroup contact

WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

 <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**/contact/contact/wsgi.py:**

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'contact.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**/contact/contact/urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('contactform.urls', namespace='contactform')),
]
```

**/contact/contactform/urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'contact'

urlpatterns = [
    path('thanks/', views.thanks, name='thanks'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

Comment: Well, you could try changing the user in the apache configuration from `contact` to `www-data`. And also, you could try settings `LogLevel debug` and looking at the error logs

Comment: Tried changing the user, no luck. Errors logs added above.

Comment: I think you try to use Python/Django as an inline PHP script. You cannot put random Django stuff in a HTML file, like with PHP: `<?php echo($form) ?>`, and expect it to render. That's not how things work with Django. You have to create an app (currently you don't have any), define the URL structure, create the form, and finally render the template through the Django template system. After that Django will know if somebody access `/contact/contact_form_endpoint_defined_in_an_app` which app's endpoint to call to render the respective form.

Comment: So first learn Django basics. Create the contact app with the corresponding URL structure, forms and templates. Make sure that everything works correctly with the Django's builtin devserver. After that, you can try to put the Django app behind the Apache2 webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me:

I needed to add the `#added lines` in `wsgi.py`
(from https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/hosting-django-sites-apache )

```
import os

import sys #added

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/contact')  #added

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'contact.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And rather than edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`, I edited `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
Alias /static /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/static
Alias /media /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/media

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /contact  /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact/wsgi.py process-group=contact

WSGIDaemonProcess contact  python-path=/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact

WSGIProcessGroup contact

<Directory  /var/www/html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Require all granted

<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

One line of your 000-default.conf is defining the path to your python executable :

```
WSGIDaemonProcess contact python-path=/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact python-home=/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact
```

If you want to let apache find the python used in the shell, you should remove the python-path argument

```
WSGIDaemonProcess contact python-home=/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact
```

Or make it point to your python3 installation

```
WSGIDaemonProcess contact python-path=/my/python3/path python-home=/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact
```

That way you will stop having a warning about python2.7 being used and it may help your project working

You should also ensure that your mod-wsgi was installed using python3 and not using python2.7

Comment: Thanks, I used your second example. I also installed and enabled libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 and that shows in the log as `Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1k mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations` But no luck :(  I edited my question with updated apache conf files.

Comment: Can you add what's in /var/log/apache2/error.log and /var/log/apache2/access.log to your question ?

Comment: Logs added in question

Comment: Are you trying to acces an *.html link ?

Or is it an url defined in your urls.py ?

Comment: Hi @Arthur, I appreciate your help. I've added more details and the urls.py files. What will be the URL for the contact form? Will it be /contact.html or /contact/ ?

Comment: First of all you should not put '/' at the end of your urls, the url will be '/contact' and you should add your contact app to the installed app in the settings.py

Comment: OK, still getting a 403 for example.com/contact   And how do I add the contact app to the installed app in the settings.py ? Add it in "INSTALLED_APPS"?

Comment: yes that's it, all the details are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models) ! Consider going through [these tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/). They're enough to answer your questions